# Unlock a logfile locked by another process linux

Tags: bash, scripts, log

I have written a script to empty/nullify a logfile once a day on my ubuntu server.

LogFile Path: `/var/log/turn.log`

I have tried below commands for this purpose:

Commands :
`sudo cp /dev/null /var/log/turn.log`
`sudo truncate -s 0 /var/log/turn.log`

The size of the file does not reduce by using any of the either commands. I suspect that the file is locked by the process currently writing logs into it.

```
$ sudo fuser /var/log/turn.log
/var/log/turn.log :    964 
$ ps 964
PID    TTY    STAT    TIME    COMMAND

964    ?      Ssl    0:54     /usr/bin/turnserver -c  /etc/turnserver.conf -o -v
$
```

How can I unlock this file so that my script can nullify the logfile everyday at a given time.

Comment: think you mean to do `sudo sh -c '> /var/log/turn.log'`

Comment: Why don't you use the standard logrotate utility for this ?  This is already installed and configured (in /etc/logrotate.conf and /etc/logrotate.d). See `man logrotate`. Also be aware that if a process has the logfile open, data wont be deleted from the disk until the process closes the file.

Comment: `killall -HUP turnserver` should re-read log file.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I unlock this file so that my script can nullify the logfile everyday at a given time.

Stop turnserver before you do

```
sudo cp /dev/null /var/log/turn.log 
sudo truncate -s 0 /var/log
```

and start it after this is done. If supported only a restart after emptying the file is also possible. I would have used `> /var/log/turn.log` as root or from crontab as root; but this also keeps the file as is until released. Truncate is not needed.

Besides altering turnsever to not lock the file all the time (using a service I would lock the file when needed and somewhere in the loop close/reopen the log) the more generic method would be to add the log to logrotate and have logrotate deal with this: compress the file and remove compressed files when older than x days. Those older logs are never touched by turnserver.

Comment: `sudo > /var/log/turn.log` is wrong syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command line, it should exchange your old log file with a new empty one. The old log file will have the `*.old` file extension.

```
sudo cp -a --attributes-only /var/log/turn.log /var/log/turn.log.new &&\
sudo ln -f /var/log/turn.log /var/log/turn.log.old &&\
sudo ln -f /var/log/turn.log.new /var/log/turn.log &&\
sudo unlink /var/log/turn.log.new && sync ||\
echo "Error: Something went wrong."
```